# Sending link in Safari via IM

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Does anyone know of a Safari mechanism (extension in Safari 5, perhaps), that will allow a person to send the current URL via instant message? Ideally, it would pop up a list of contacts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Adium, you can send the current Safari link by clicking on the toolbar item "Insert link to active page in Safari" on the chat window with a contact.

If you need to send it directly from Safari, you may need to create an automator action or applescript service.

Comment: That works for me. I've been using a lot since you mentioned it. Thanks.